# Неполное затемнение экрана при появлении модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, background-color

Есть модальное окно

```js
let fullwindow = document.getElementById('fullblock');
/*let modal = document.getElementById('myModal');*/
let modalcontent = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-content')[0];
let loginlink = document.getElementsByClassName('loginandsignup')[0];

let elemclose = document.getElementsByClassName("closeregwindow")[0];

let footer = document.getElementById('pageFooter');
let catalogbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('catalogbutton')[0];
let inputfind = document.getElementsByClassName('inputsearch')[0];
let searchbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('searchbutton')[0];


loginlink.onclick = function() {
  // footer.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  catalogbtn.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  inputfind.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  searchbtn.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  fullwindow.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  //            footer.style.backgroundColor="white";
  modalcontent.style.display = "block";
}


elemclose.onclick = function() {
  modalcontent.style.display = "none";
}


window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == fullwindow) {
    modalcontent.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.loginandsignup {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-self: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 6;
  position: fixed;
  /*position: relative;*/
  background-color: #E1BEE7;
  /*
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 25%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    */
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 0;
  border: 5px solid #7B1FA2;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  /*background-color: rgb(0,0,0);*/
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  /*
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
    */
}


/*
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}
*/

.closeregwindow {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.closeregwindow:hover,
.closeregwindow:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #9C27B0;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #9C27B0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">-->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Test Example</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../simplebar/packages/simplebar/src/simplebar.css"></link>-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/commons.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/subcategory.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/vendors.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/template.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/vendors.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/fonts.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/components.bundle.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/components.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/common.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/headerIndex.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/indexIndex.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles__ltr.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stylesheet.css"></link>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/testsite.css"></link>-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/newtestsite.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stylesheet.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/productcardblockstyle.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../fonts/fonts.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/commonstylesformenuitems.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic" media="all">



  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  </script>

</head>


<body class="bodyclass">

  <div id="fullblock">
    <div id="dropdownwindow">
      <div class="contentdropdownwindow">
        <div class="CatalogMenuLeft">
          <div class="catalogheader">
            <div class="flexline1">
              <div class="crossline">
              </div>
              <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar1">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flexline2">
              <div class="windowheader">
                <h4>Каталог</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar2">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flexline3">
              <div class="bottompart">
              </div>
              <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar3">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--<div class="flexcontent">-->
          <div class="windowmenulist" id="menulist">
            <div class="menulistitem" id="smartphonesandgadgets">
              Смартфоны и гаджеты
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="notebooksandpcs">
              Ноутбуки и компьютеры
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="tvsaudiovideohifi">
              Телевизоры, аудио-видео, Hi-Fi
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="householdappliancesforhomeandkitchen">
              Бытовая техника для дома и кухни
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="constructionandrepair">
              Строительство и ремонт
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="houseandcottage">
              Дом и дача
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="photosvideossecuritysystems">
              Фото, видео, системы безопасности
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="automotiveproducts">
              Автотовары
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="officesuppliesfurnitureandofficeequipment">
              Канцтовары, Мебель и Офисная техника
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="beautyandhealth">
              Красота и здоровье
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="sportsandrecreation">
              Спорт и отдых
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="productsforgamers">
              Товары для геймеров
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="discountedproducts">
              Уцененные товары
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="giftcertificates">
              Подарочные сертификаты
            </div>
            <div class="menulistitem" id="services">
              Сервисы и услуги
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--</div>-->
        </div>
        <div class="myscroll">

        </div>
        <div id="dropdownwindowright">
          <div class="crosslineright">
            <div class="close">&times;</div>
          </div>
          <div class="CatalogMenuSearch">
            <div id="SearchBlock">
              <div id="SearchInputdiv">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск по товарам" id="SearchInput">
              </div>
              <div id="SearchButtondiv">
                <button id="SearchButton"><svg class=" Icon" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5.22703 5.22703C7.86307 2.591 12.1369 2.591 14.773 5.22703C17.2298 7.68382 17.3968 11.5632 15.2742 14.2135L19.0607 18L18 19.0607L14.2135 15.2742C11.5632 17.3968 7.68381 17.2298 5.22703 14.773C2.59099 12.1369 2.59099 7.86307 5.22703 5.22703ZM13.7123 6.28769C11.6621 4.23744 8.33794 4.23744 6.28769 6.28769C4.23744 8.33795 4.23744 11.6621 6.28769 13.7123C8.33794 15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 13.7123 13.7123C15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 8.33795 13.7123 6.28769Z"></path></svg></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="CatalogMenuRight" id="CatalogMenuRight">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="CatalogFreeSpace">
</div>-->
    <header id="pageHeader">
      
      <div class="headerinsides">
        <span class="flexcitylinkwrapper">
        <a href="#" class="flexcitylink">
                <span class="icon">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="Sg" width="16" height="16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M8.057 8a2.012 2.012 0 01-2.019-2c0-1.103.906-2 2.02-2 1.113 0 2.018.897 2.018 2s-.905 2-2.019 2zm0-5C6.387 3 5.03 4.346 5.03 6s1.358 3 3.028 3 3.029-1.346 3.029-3-1.359-3-3.029-3zm0 11.777C6.852 13.5 3.01 9.177 3.01 6c0-2.757 2.264-5 5.047-5 2.784 0 5.047 2.243 5.047 5 0 3.174-3.841 7.5-5.047 8.777zM8.057 0C4.717 0 2 2.691 2 6c0 4.159 5.468 9.623 5.7 9.854a.509.509 0 00.714 0c.233-.23 5.7-5.695 5.7-9.854 0-3.309-2.716-6-6.057-6z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
                </span>
        <span class="labelforicon">
                 Краснодар
                </span>
        </a>
        </span>
        <span class="intermediatespace">
                </span>
        <span class="telephonenumber">
                8 (800) 600 3900 (круглосуточно)
                </span>
        <span class="addressandworkschedule">
                    Адрес и график работы
                </span>
        <span class="payment">
                    Оплата
                </span>
        <span class="delivery">
                    Доставка
                </span>
      </div>
      <div class="headerinsidessecondrow" id="secondrowheader">
        <!--<button class="catalogbutton">Каталог товаров</button>-->
        <button class="catalogbutton">Каталог товаров</button>

        <span class="betweenspace">
</span>

        <span class="findinfo">
        <input placeholder="Поиск среди 10000 товаров" class="inputsearch"></input>
        <button class="searchbutton">Найти</button>
</span>

        <span class="secondbetweenspace">
</span>

        <span class="loginandsignup">
    <!--<div class="loginandsignupinner">-->
        <div class="loginsignupimg">
            <img src="../images/header_profile-icon.png">
        </div>
        <div class="loginsignuptext">
            Войти
        </div>
    <!--</div>-->
</span>

        <span class="basket">
    <span class="loginsignupimg">
        <img src="../images/header_cart-icon.png">
    </span>
        <span class="loginsignuptext">
        Корзина
    </span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </header>


    <!--<div id="myModal" class="modal">-->


    <div class="modal-content" id="modaldialog">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span><h2>Шапка модального окна</h2></span>
        <span class="closeregwindow"><!--<a href="#secondrowheader">-->&times;<!--</a>--></span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Какой-то текст в теле модального окна</p>
        <p>Ещё другой текст...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <h3>Футер модального окна</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--</div>-->

    <div class="contentpart">
      <div class="leftmenu">
        
    
      </div>

      <div class="centerareawrapper">
        <div class="centerarea">
        </div>
        <div id="pagination">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="rightmenu">
      </div>
    </div>


    <footer id="pageFooter">
      <div class="b-footer__container">
        <div class="b-footer-menu">
          <div class="b-footer-menu__column">
            <div class="b-footer-menu__col" data-footer-col="">
              <div class="b-footer-menu__header" data-accordion-btn="0">
                <a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/about-us">
              Интернет-магазин
            </a>
                <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
              </div>
              <ul class="b-footer-menu__list" data-accordion-target="0" style="display: none;">
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/about-us" class="b-footer-menu__link">О нас</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/delivery" class="b-footer-menu__link">Доставка</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/pay" class="b-footer-menu__link">Оплата</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/kredit" class="b-footer-menu__link">Покупка в кредит</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/e-catalog" class="b-footer-menu__link">Электронный каталог</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/special-offers" class="b-footer-menu__link">Акции</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/news" class="b-footer-menu__link">Новости</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/reviews" class="b-footer-menu__link">Обзоры</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/personal" class="b-footer-menu__link">Условия продажи<br> и политика обработки<br> персональных данных</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/services/card2card" class="b-footer-menu__link">Денежные переводы<br> с карты на карту</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/services/creditpayment" class="b-footer-menu__link">Оплата кредита онлайн</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/services/moneytransfer" class="b-footer-menu__link">Денежные переводы онлайн</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="b-footer-menu__column">
            <div class="b-footer-menu__col" data-footer-col="">
              <div class="b-footer-menu__header" data-accordion-btn="1">
                <a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/company">
              Компания
            </a>
                <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
              </div>
              <ul class="b-footer-menu__list" data-accordion-target="1" style="display: none;">
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/history" class="b-footer-menu__link">Кто мы</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/catalog/elektronika-optom" class="b-footer-menu__link">Корпоративным клиентам</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/owner_of_real" class="b-footer-menu__link">Арендодателям</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/charity" class="b-footer-menu__link">Благотворительность</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://job.svyaznoy.ru/" target="_blank" class="b-footer-menu__link">Работа в «Связном»</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/contacts" class="b-footer-menu__link">Контакты</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/anticorruption" class="b-footer-menu__link">Политика по&nbsp;противодействию<br>коррупции</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="b-footer-menu__column">
            <div class="b-footer-menu__col" data-footer-col="">
              <div class="b-footer-menu__header" data-accordion-btn="2">
                <a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/help">
              Помощь покупателю
            </a>
                <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
              </div>
              <ul class="b-footer-menu__list" data-accordion-target="2" style="display: none;">
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/support/feedback/add-review" class="b-footer-menu__link">Обратная связь</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/shops" class="b-footer-menu__link">Адреса магазинов</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/obmen_vozvrat_remont" class="b-footer-menu__link">Обмен, возврат и ремонт</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/guarantee" class="b-footer-menu__link">Гарантия</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/support/repair-status" target="_blank" class="b-footer-menu__link">Статус ремонта</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/support/contacts/addresses" target="_blank" class="b-footer-menu__link">Адреса сервисных центров</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/service" class="b-footer-menu__link">Дополнительные услуги и сервис</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="b-footer-menu__col" data-footer-col="">
              <div class="b-footer-menu__header" data-accordion-btn="3">
                <a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/press_center">
              Пресс-центр
            </a>
                <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
              </div>
              <ul class="b-footer-menu__list" data-accordion-target="3" style="display: none;">
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/history" class="b-footer-menu__link">История</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/mission" class="b-footer-menu__link">Миссия и ценности</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/news/press" class="b-footer-menu__link">Пресс-релизы</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/media_about_us" class="b-footer-menu__link">СМИ о нас</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UhyjwJ6wZbUX-UxlFVTELnYi8bnxuhmg" target="_blank" class="b-footer-menu__link">Фотографии</a></li>
                <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/contacts_for_media" class="b-footer-menu__link">Контакты для прессы</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="b-footer-menu__column">
            <div class="b-footer-menu__col is-mobile-not">
              <div class="b-footer-menu__contacts">
                <div class="b-footer-menu__header _xl">
                  <a href="tel:84952870000">8 (495) 287-00-00</a>
                </div>
                Интернет-магазин
                <div class="b-footer-menu__header _xl">
                  <a href="tel:88007005000">8 (800) 700-50-00</a>
                </div>
                Связной Поддержка
                <div class="b-footer-menu__header _xl">
                  <a href="tel:88007009922">8 (800) 700-99-22</a>
                </div>
                Корпоративным клиентам
              </div>
              <div class="b-footer-menu__socials">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/svyaznoy.ru" target="_blank">
                  <i class="icon-fb"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="https://vk.com/svyaznoy" target="_blank">
                  <i class="icon-vk"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/svyaznoy_ru" target="_blank">
                  <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/svyaznoy_russia/?hl=ru" target="_blank">
                  <i class="icon-instagram"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="b-footer-menu__ga">
                <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.svyaznoy.shop" target="_blank" class="_gp" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=ru.svyaznoy.shop&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a><br>
                <a href="https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/svaznoj-internet-magazin-elektroniki/id1062774471" target="_blank" class="_as" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/apps.apple.com\/ru\/app\/svaznoj-internet-magazin-elektroniki\/id1062774471&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
                <br>
                <a href="https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/marketshare/app/C102123139?locale=ru_RU&amp;source=appshare&amp;subsource=C102123139" target="_blank" class="_ag" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/appgallery.cloud.huawei.com\/marketshare\/app\/C102123139?locale=ru_RU&amp;source=appshare&amp;subsource=C102123139&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="b-footer-border">
          <div class="b-footer-border__inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="b-footer-rel" data-footer-col="">
          <div class="b-footer-menu__header is-mobile-only" data-accordion-btn="4">
            Другие проекты
            <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="b-footer-rel__list" data-accordion-target="4" style="display: none;">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="b-footer-bottom">
          <div class="b-footer-copy-wrapper">
            <div class="b-footer-copy">© ООО «Сеть Связной» 2002—2021. Все права защищены. Указанная в интернет-магазине цена товаров и условия их приобретения действительны на текущую дату.</div>
          </div>
          <a class="b-footer-stop-covid _big lazy lazy-loaded" href="https://ecomvscovid.ru/" target="_blank" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.svyaznoy.ru/upload/web/svyaznoy/img/footer/covidlogo.svg&quot;);">
        Зона безопасного сервиса. Стоп COVID.
      </a>
        </div>
        <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile">
          <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__row">
            <div class="b-footer-menu__socials">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/svyaznoy.ru" target="_blank">
                <i class="icon-fb"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://vk.com/svyaznoy" target="_blank">
                <i class="icon-vk"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://twitter.com/svyaznoy_ru" target="_blank">
                <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/svyaznoy_russia/?hl=ru" target="_blank">
                <i class="icon-instagram"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__right-col">
              <a class="b-footer-stop-covid _small lazy" data-original="https://cdn.svyaznoy.ru/upload/web/svyaznoy/img/footer/covidlogo.svg" href="https://ecomvscovid.ru/" target="_blank">
            Зона безопасного сервиса. Стоп COVID.
          </a>
              <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__tel">
                <a class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__tel-link" href="tel:8 (495) 287-00-00">8 (495) 287-00-00</a>
                <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__tel-descr">Интернет магазин</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="b-footer-menu__ga _mobile">
            <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.svyaznoy.shop" target="_blank" class="_gp" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=ru.svyaznoy.shop&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
            <a href="https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/svaznoj-internet-magazin-elektroniki/id1062774471" target="_blank" class="_as" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/apps.apple.com\/ru\/app\/svaznoj-internet-magazin-elektroniki\/id1062774471&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
            <a href="https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/marketshare/app/C102123139?locale=ru_RU&amp;source=appshare&amp;subsource=C102123139" target="_blank" class="_ag" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/appgallery.cloud.huawei.com\/marketshare\/app\/C102123139?locale=ru_RU&amp;source=appshare&amp;subsource=C102123139&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </footer>

  </div>
  <!--
<script src="js/commons.bundle.js.Без названия"></script>
<script src="js/subcategory.bundle.js.Без названия"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="js/testsite3.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="../simplebar/packages/simplebar/src/simplebar.js"></script>-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/currentversion.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Экран должен затемняться при появлении модального окна

```
fullwindow.style.backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
```

но несмотря на это экран выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Футер не затемняется. Как добиться полного затемнения экрана? `#fullblock` - это аналог полного экрана `.modal` (см. ответ @humster_spb).

Comment: @Igor помогите пожалуйста (вы меня очень сильно выручали: может быть и в этот раз поможете).

Comment: Подтягивайтесь все кто может.

Comment: хорошо бы сразу формулировать заголовок вопроса с более конкретным содержанием, отражающим суть вопроса. Это оч. важно и облегчает  поиск ответов на подобные вопросы в будущем.

Answer (score 5):

Возможно @Igor что-то подскажет Вам непосредственно по Вашему коду, а я просто приведу пример, как лучше реализовать модалку.

В большинстве случаев модальные окна проектируются по такой схеме: есть само окно, которое имеет `position: fixed`, растягивается на всю площадь экрана и создаёт эффект затемнения, а внутри него уже блок `modal-content`, содержащий информацию:

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $('.modal').css('display','block');
})

$('.close').on('click',function(){
    $('.modal').css('display','none');
})
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  display: none;
}
.modal-content {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  position: relative;
}
.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -25px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Шапка модального окна</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Какой-то текст в теле модального окна</p>
      <p>Ещё другой текст...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Футер модального окна</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Заголовок страницы</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam ducimus non, doloremque voluptatibus cupiditate qui quas dolores quaerat porro eligendi velit, architecto, laboriosam veniam suscipit. Quasi, et inventore! Totam, commodi!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam ducimus non, doloremque voluptatibus cupiditate qui quas dolores quaerat porro eligendi velit, architecto, laboriosam veniam suscipit. Quasi, et inventore! Totam, commodi!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam ducimus non, doloremque voluptatibus cupiditate qui quas dolores quaerat porro eligendi velit, architecto, laboriosam veniam suscipit. Quasi, et inventore! Totam, commodi!</p>
<button>Открыть модальное окно</button>
```

Comment: я изменил вопрос. Есть соображения по новому вопросу?

Comment: лучше создать новый вопрос или оставить отредактированным текущий вопрос?

Comment: @krasnodarprogrammer, в вопросе нужно сделать воспроизводимый пример конкретной проблемы - не копировать всю разметку сайта с линками, из которых сюда ничего не подтягивается, а взять только нужный кусок кода, нужные стили, скрипты, всё это упаковать в сниппет, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Выполнить код" можно было посмотреть, в чём проблема. Сейчас разобраться в Вашем коде невозможно, увы, а в сниппете ничего толком не воспроизводится.